# Cálculo de Chi-Quadrado para proporções

Tags: r

Tenho um DF com proporções de óbitos na população A e B. Quero fazer o teste para verificar a independência das populações. Segue o meu DF:

```
DATE<- c("2017/jan","2017/feb","2017/mar","2017/apr","2017/may","2017/jun","2017/jul","2017/aug","2017/sep","2017/oct","2017/nov","2017/dec","2018/jan","2018/feb","2018/mar","2018/apr","2018/may","2018/jun","2018/jul","2018/aug","2018/sep","2018/oct","2018/nov","2018/dec","2019/jan","2019/feb","2019/mar","2019/apr","2019/may","2019/jun","2019/jul","2019/aug","2019/sep","2019/oct","2019/nov","2019/dec")
POP_A<- c(0.0304,0.0394,0.0346,0.0331,0.0411,0.0453,0.0443,0.0476,0.0423,0.0331,0.0416,0.0368,0.0407,0.0439,0.0404,0.0414,0.0464,0.0414,0.0494,0.0497,0.041,0.0454,0.0372,0.0448,0.0464,0.034,0.0514,0.0462,0.0416,0.0428,0.058,0.0392,0.0397,0.051,0.0435,0.0437)
POP_B<- c(0.01,0.0242,0.031,0.0155,0.0324,0.0274,0.04,0.0251,0.0208,0.0255,0.0371,0.0211,0.0265,0.0291,0.0202,0.0233,0.019,0.0213,0.0103,0.034,0.0196,0.0175,0.0233,0.038,0.0327,0.0235,0.0236,0.0231,0.0228,0.0172,0.0211,0.0272,0.0398,0.0218,0.0301,0.031)
DF<- data.frame(DATE,POP_A,POP_B)
```

Como faria o teste Qui-Quadrado das populações A e B?

Comment: Quais são os totais das populações? E quer o teste por mês?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não creio que os dados tal como estão na pergunta cheguem para realizar um teste de qui-quadrado de independência. Para o fazer são precisos dados que permitam calcular contagens (tabela de contingência) e a partir dessas contagens as proporções. Além disso, não é claro se se quer saber da independência das duas variáveis, `POP_A` e `POP_B` ao longo do tempo, mês a mês (variável `DATE`). Veja a discussão em comentários à [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/457530/82237) da usuária [@Danielly Xavier](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/156165/danielly-xavier).

Eu começaria por **ver os dados**.
Em primeiro lugar, traçar um gráfico da relação entre as duas variáveis contínuas.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(Hmisc)

ggplot(DF, aes(POP_A, POP_B)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não parece haver qualquer regularidade assinalável, as populações parecem ser independentes.

Agora traça-se um gráfico das proporções em ordem ao tempo. Para isso vou reformatar os dados para o formato longo com a função `pivot_longer` do pacote `tidyr` que faz parte do `tidyverse`.

```
DF %>%
  mutate(DATE = ymd(paste(DATE, '01'))) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches('POP'),
    names_to = 'POP',
    values_to = 'VALOR'
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(DATE, VALOR, colour = POP)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais uma vez não parece haver qualquer relação entre as variáveis.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, identifique que categorias você está comparando. Qual é a categoria que você está comparando? Para calcular o X² você precisará de 4 categorias: sucesso A, sucesso B, fracasso A e fracasso B.
Nesse caso, seu data.frame deverá ter 4 colunas, com as categorias que você está comparando.
Abaixo um exemplo de como calculei o X² para uma amostra de óbitos por dengue e por outras causas.

```
#teste X2

##pressupostos
## variáveis categóricas

#exemplo: houve maior mortalidade por dengue quando comparado às outras causas?

library(foreign)
obtdf18= read.dbf('OBTDF18.dbf')

dobt = subset(obtdf18, obtdf18$CAUSABAS == 'A91')

#tabela de contigência
## mortes por dengue
denobt = NROW(dobt)

## mortes por outras causas
obtr = NROW(obtdf18) - denobt

## casos de dengue
dtot = NROW(den_14)- denobt

## restante da população
popr = popdf$POP - dtot
tab_cont = c(denobt, obtr, dtot, popr)
tab_cont = data.frame(rbind(tab_cont, tab_cont, tab_cont))

#calculando X²
tab_cont2 <- cbind(tab_cont, t(apply(tab_cont, 1, function(x) {
ch <- chisq.test(x)
c(unname(ch$statistic), ch$p.value)})))
colnames(tab_cont2) = c('denobt', 'obtr', 'dtot', 'popr', 'x-squared', 'p-value')
```

Comment: Os dados da pergunta são proporções e `NROW` dá totais.

Comment: Você vai precisar separar em categorias. Transformar esses números em quantidades, para calcular o X².

Comment: Nesse caso, somente a proporção não é capaz de te indicar se a diferença é significativa. Você precisa do N da população para testar isso. Assim, você vai montar uma tabela de contingência com óbitos em expostos a A, óbitos em expostos a B, sobreviventes em A e sobreviventes em B. Depois disso, você irá calcular o X². Você pode usar uma linha para calcular em cada mês e transformar isso em um DF, conforme o exemplo.

Comment: Sim, é mais ou menos isso o que eu digo na primeira parte do comentário à pergunta. Assim, quando muitopode-se fazer um teste de independência de variáveis contínuas.Por exemplo, o [teste de Hoeffding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_independence_test), ver também o [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/103595/171783)